# Turn solution into a pdf or doc file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pdf

This might seem like an odd question, but I need to turn my code into a pdf - so I can hand it in. Yes sadly the school system demands the code on cd as a pdf. What I could do is open every class in my solution and copy paste it. But - as a programmer - I am lazy and would like to know if Visual Studio has any feature for this? or if there is any other way?

Edit: A third party program that iterates through all files in a folder, opens the file and copies it's content, into a pdf file. Would do aswell - it does not have to be within Visual Studio.

Comment: if your school demands this, surely someone has already solved the problem of converting all of a  solutions code files to pdf?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/389318/looking-for-software-that-will-batch-convert-a-folder-tree-containing-chm-files

Comment: Mitch, that's what I thought and why I am here. Because I believe the same, there must be a tool for this out there. The school gives us no tool for this either.

Comment: As a rule schools don't like getting reams of code to mark. If you've got too much to PDF by hand are you sure you haven't written too much? (I always used to)

Comment: I don't think there is a "too much". I think we have about 10k lines of code. It's the final project. I don't believe the teachers are going to look through it all - we've written som documentation for them but they also want the code, sadly - the school's rules not theirs they say. I knew it, I should just have made that "Hello world" console app ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got tired of waiting, here's what I came up with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace GetFileContents
{
    class Program
    {
        static string types = ".js,.cshtml,.cs,.less,.css";
        private static string text = "";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //This folder wraps the whole thing.
            string folderPath = @"C:\randomFolderWhereProjectIs\";

            string s = IterateIt(Directory.GetDirectories(folderPath).ToList());
            //Save to file or whatever I just used the text visualiser in Visual Studio
        }

        private static string IterateIt(List<string> l)
        {

            foreach (var path in l)
            {
                var files = Directory.GetFiles(path).Select(c => new FileInfo(c)).Where(c => types.Split(',').Contains(c.Extension));

                foreach (var fileInfo in files)
                {
                    text += fileInfo.Name + "\r\n";
                    using (StreamReader reader = fileInfo.OpenText())
                    {
                        text += reader.ReadToEnd() + "\r\n";
                    }
                }
                text = IterateIt(Directory.GetDirectories(path).ToList());
            }
            return text;
        }


    }
}
```